# Importing from CSV to salesrule_coupon. Notice: Undefined index: sku

Tags: magento2, import, csv, coupon

I've added on System > Data Transfer > Import another option in order to populate the table salesrule_coupon and i got on my csv the following:

```
rule_id,code,usage_limit,usage_per_customer,times_used,created_at,type
1,'R56Y2CU5FX8L',0,0,0,'2017-09-05 11:19:21',1
1,'705E77MMDK3E',0,0,0,'2017-11-22 22:09:57',1
```

On etc/import.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="salesrule_coupon" label="Cupones" model="<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Coupon" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

then on Model Coupon:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: oscar
 * Date: 22-01-19
 * Time: 11:07 AM
 */

namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Model;


use <Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Coupon\RowValidatorInterface as ValidatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;

class Coupon extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
{
    const ID = 'coupon_id';
    const RULE_ID = 'rule_id';
    const CODE = 'code';
    const USAGE_LIMIT = 'usage_limit';
    const USAGE_PER_CUSTOMER = 'usage_per_customer';
    const TIMES_USED = 'times_used';
    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const TYPE = 'type';

    const TABLE_Entity = 'salesrule_coupon';
    /**
     * Validation failure message template definitions
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messageTemplates = [
        ValidatorInterface::ERROR_CODE_IS_EMPTY => 'Code is empty',
    ];
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [self::CODE];
    /**
     * If we should check column names
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;
    /**
     * Valid column names
     *
     * @array
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        self::RULE_ID,
        self::CODE,
        self::USAGE_LIMIT,
        self::USAGE_PER_CUSTOMER,
        self::TIMES_USED,
        self::CREATED_AT,
        self::TYPE
    ];
    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;
    protected $_validators = [];
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_connection;
    protected $_resource;
    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
    }
    public function getValidColumnNames()
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        echo "entro2";
        return 'salesrule_coupon';
    }
    /**
     * Row validation.
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum)
    {
        $title = false;
        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }
        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;
        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }
    /**
     * Create Advanced message data from raw data.
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return bool Result of operation.
     */
    protected function _importData()
    {
        $this->saveEntity();
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Save Message
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function saveEntity()
    {
        $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Save and replace data message
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $listTitle = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                    $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface, $rowNum);
                    continue;
                }
                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                    continue;
                }
                $rowCode= $rowData[self::CODE];
                $listTitle[] = $rowCode;
                $entityList[$rowCode][] = [
                    //self::ID => $rowData[self::ID],
                    self::RULE_ID => $rowData[self::RULE_ID],
                    self::CODE => $rowData[self::CODE],
                    self::USAGE_LIMIT => $rowData[self::USAGE_LIMIT],
                    self::USAGE_PER_CUSTOMER => $rowData[self::USAGE_PER_CUSTOMER],
                    self::TIMES_USED => $rowData[self::TIMES_USED],
                    self::CREATED_AT => $rowData[self::CREATED_AT],
                    self::TYPE => $rowData[self::TYPE],
                ];
            }
            if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $behavior) {
                if ($listTitle) {
                    if ($this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique(  $listTitle), self::TABLE_Entity)) {
                        $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
                    }
                }
            } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Save message to customtable.
     *
     * @param array $priceData
     * @param string $table
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table)
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
            $entityIn = [];
            foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $entityIn[] = $row;
                }
            }
            if ($entityIn) {
                $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityIn,[
                    self::RULE_ID,
                    self::CODE,
                    self::USAGE_LIMIT,
                    self::USAGE_PER_CUSTOMER,
                    self::TIMES_USED,
                    self::CREATED_AT,
                    self::TYPE
                ]);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And then when i click on Check Data returns the following:
Notice: Undefined index: sku in ...vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import/Entity/AbstractEntity.php on line 411

Please help! :(
THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got it solved i just changed the

```
\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
```

for

```
\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractEntity
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: this resolved the error, but after import is clicked facing this error,systemException Additional data: Error in data structure: entity values are mixed

Answer (score 0):

that solution didn't work for me, however i had to create a class that extends from: `\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity`
and then override the method 
`_saveValidatedBunches` , there is a line of code (411):

```
$skuSet[$rowData['sku']] = true;
```

so, I replaced that line by:

```
if (array_key_exists('sku', $rowData)) {
    $skuSet[$rowData['sku']] = true;
}
```

I got that solution from the official git issue 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.10/app/code/Magento/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/AbstractEntity.php